# Protecting a git branch in Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops

I would like only explicitly permitted developers to merge into a 'master' branch.  I've found the location of the security settings but nothing seems to allow me to say 'that branch, only allow Rob to merge into it'.  Any specific guidance please?

Comment: You probably don't see that because as far as Git is concerned, it doesn't exist.  Rob owns all the branches in his copy of the repo.

Comment: Ok, so how do I stop someone merging code that hasn't been approved into the central repository for 'master' which will then be shared with anyone else that pulls code?

Comment: By embracing the concept of DVCS.  If there's a "central repository" at all, its only specialness is that everyone knows to pull from.it.  If you want to keep a branch clean, then don't let pushes happen arbitrarily -- have the would-be pusher send you a pull request from their fork, which you or someone in charge can review before merging in.

Comment: So should my question be 'how do I specifically configure VSO git to allow team members to pull code and allow only certain people to push into a specified branch'?  For example GitLab allows this: https://about.gitlab.com/2014/11/26/keeping-your-code-protected/

Comment: There's not really such a thing as "only allowing certain people to push into a specified branch".  There's "only allowing certain people to push, *period*".  Pushers can update any branch.  If you don't trust people to update correctly, then don't let them push -- have them make the changes in their own copy and then issue a pull request.

Comment: VSO might have some special thing like GitLab does.  I haven't seen it, and it's not a feature built into Git, but it might be in there somewhere if MS has meddled enough.  So the first question to ask is, "is it even possible?".

Comment: Ok, thanks cHao.  Is there a particular permission I can set to disallow pushes? There's nothing specific on the project permissions pages that I can find.

Comment: @RobEllis: You can do this if you host your git repositories in [Gerrit](http://code.google.com/p/gerrit) - it allows to set permissions to push per branch

Comment: You can set permissions per branch in VSO and TFS.

Comment: @cHao, it's true that Git itself doesn't provide branch security, but TFS2013 and VSO do. You can configure a number of items, including force push, contribute (push), branch creation and tag creation in a repository. For Pull-request workflows you'd be able to deny push permission on the target branch, but would still allow branch creation and tag creation.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can protect MASTER in VSTS pretty easily as TFS provides enterprise Git capabilities. There are two ways to achieve this.

### 1) Git Branch Permissions

In the administration pages under the Version Control tab you can change permission for each published branch. You need to maintain access at the repo level, however on MASTER you can change "Contributor" commit permission to "not configured". You can then add only Rob...

[image: VSTS Git Branch permissions]

Oh... Always use "not set" rather than "deny" as deny always overrides.

### 2) Git Branch Policies

VSTS has introduces the idea of Branch Policies. These Branch Policies can be applied to any branch but are traditionally applied to MASTER.

[image: VSTS Git Branch Policies]

Here you can apply multiple policies to reflect you needs... I always set

Comment: Martin, can you add a few screenshots? f you don't know where to look, this may be hard to find.

Comment: You can't change `Inherited Allow` into `Not Set`.  TFS senses `Not Set` and automatically looks to the parent for inheritance.  If it is set on a Parent, it forces that setting.

Comment: Also, if you change the Project's Contributors>Contribute setting to `Not Set`, then only admins or the Branch-Creator can contribute to created branches.

Answer (score 9):

I found I had to go through slightly more steps to get this done

There are 2 places to define groups in visual studio online - at the collection level and at the project level.

At the collection level I created an admin group and created a developers group. I only wanted people in the admin group to have write access to master branch in my repository.

At the project level, I added developers and admins group to the project team.
In the project contributors group I removed the project team and added only the developer group

In the project administrators group I added the collection level admin group.

Then on version control tab on the master branch I set contribute=deny for the contributors group

As administrators are not members of the contributors group the deny permission is not applied to them and they can still push changes to master - either directly or through approving pull requests

Answer (score 2):

I successfully created the (2) types of groups based off of @anthonybrown. I wanted to, however, give some screenshots to further help the explanation of resolving the ability to restrict users from deleting, pushing, and contributing to the `master` branch (or other branch(es) of your choosing) **on a repository level base, not a global level.**

Note that based on our VSTS, we already had users added to the "global" team. I did not remove these users, but instead added them to (2) separate groups.

- Developers
- Administrators

1) Go to your base VSTS screen (this will default to `/_projects` in the URL.

[image]

2) Click on the cog and select "Security"

[image]

3) On the far left side, select "Create Group", and name it "Developers". Once the group is created, select the group, and in the middle section, select "Members". Add all users that you **DO NOT** want to have contribute rights to the "master" branch to this group. (note - your users must already be added to VSTS prior to this step).

[image]

4) Create the "Administrators" group and add the users that you **DO WANT** to have access. (note - if your users in the "Administrators" group are already added to VSTS at either the global or project level you can skip this step. I did it regardless).

5) Go back to the VSTS home page (/_projects) and select your repository that you want to restrict access to the master branch. Select "Version Control". On the left side, select the "master" branch. In the middle section, select "Security". Add the "Developers group. Select the "Developers" group (once added) and set the access to "Deny" for:

- Contribute (this will be pushing
- Edit policies
- Force push
- Manage permissions

[image]

Comment: So you're adding devs to a group and then denying the group operations on the branch? Why don't you deny "Exempt from policy enforcement"?

Answer (score 0):

I usually create a special VSO group like "Devs" and then place the developers in it. Then, I use the group as a member group of project Contributors and then specifically on the branch I want to protect, I use the "Devs" group and set Contribute to Deny, thus only members of the "Devs" group have the contribution denied, but e.g. Project Admins can still push in it.

If you set Contribute to Deny directly on the Contributors group then nobody can push in the branch, not even Administrators and not even if you specifically set Allow on their Contribute, simply because Deny is stronger than Allow - unless you do some vaster changes to the original groups.

Comment: By default, the users are part of contributors by being in the Project Team team.  How do you put them into the "Devs" group?

Comment: Go to "admin"/"Control panel -> your project", tab Security. There you can manage the groups. Basically, create new group, add users to that group, go to contributors, remove the users and add the newly created group.

Comment: What if some of your "Devs" are also the administrators? Won't this lock them out?

Comment: I have administrators...well that is only myself...in a separate group and treat them completely separately.