# Protect Git branch in Visual Studio Team Services like in GitHub

Tags: git, git-flow, azure-devops

I would like to protect some branches in my Visual Studio Team Services Git Repository, similar to like it is possible in GitHub. My use case is similar but not identical to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28134314/protecting-a-git-branch-in-visual-studio-online).

We're using GitFlow with `master` and `develop` branch. Here are my requirements:

- Into the `master` branch I would only like to allow merge commits. Direct committing to `master` branch should be denied for all developers. Merge commits (= Finishing a Git-Flow release or hotfix) should be allowed for all developers.
- Commits to the `develop` branch should only be allowed through Pull Requests. Any developer should be allowed to merge Pull Requests, but not be allowed to directly commit to `develop`

Since we have quite a lot of repositories setup should be easy or it should be possible to automatize the settings through REST API.

GitHub can handle these scenarios easily with its protect branch settings. I couldn't find anything similar in the Branch Policies of Visual Studio Team Services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that branch policies are the feature you're looking for in VSTS.

For your develop or master branch, you probably want to check the "Require a minimum number of reviewers" box to enforce all changes coming in through PRs, and blocking direct pushes.  If you really don't care about having the review requirement, you can check the "Allow users to approved their own changes" box - but getting reviewers is probably a good practice to enable anyway.

The other feature you get from protected branches in GH is the ability to block force pushes.  This is controlled with a permission in VSTS, which can be set at the repo or branch level - it's called "Rewrite and destroy history (force push)".

This MSDN topic has more details and screenshots for setting policies: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Code/git/branch-policies

All of these settings can be configured via REST.  Here's a link to the policy API: https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/policy/configurations

Note, when using the REST APIs, you can configure policies for multiple branches at once, and even set policies for wildcards, i.e. enforce that all branches under release/* require code review.

Comment: Thanks. For the `master` branch I don't want to use pull requests. We're using Git-Flow and I want to only allow commits if they are coming from finishing a Git-Flow release (which is a `git merge --no-ff` operation). Direct commits should be blocked. Is there a policy for this?

Comment: Accepting this as answer for the first point. Regarding the second point (protect master branch) I got an answer from Microsoft that this is currently not available but may eventually will be supported in the future.