# Automatically deleting branches when completing pull requests

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-branch, pull-request

My company uses VSTS with git.  When I complete a pull request into the develop branch in VSTS the check box to delete the feature branch is automatically checked, but it won't delete unless I change the permissions on the feature branch to allow an administrators user group that I'm a member of to Rewrite and destroy history (force push).

It's kind of tedious to do this every time I complete a pull request, but I'm not crazy about the idea of giving all members of this administrators user group the ability to delete feature branches all the time. It seems like there could be accidental deletions.  I do feel pretty comfortable with deleting the develop branch when I'm in the process of completing a pull request that's been reviewed and approved.  Is there a third option as far as permissions?  How does your company have the policies set as far as being able to delete feature branches?

Comment: "destroy history for the feature branch" - There is no such thing as a branch history (it's a common mistake though). Branches can be simplified to pointers to specific commits (that's what is stored by git anyways): if Ilook inside the ".git/refs/heads/master" file, i get "a1781736795d91a44a4cd4557b06011c6dbba96e" for one of my projects (which is the commit id the master branch is currently on)

Comment: The permission is called Rewrite and destroy history (force push).  I've updated my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 5):

IMHO, I think you should push the responsibility to **Complete** pull requests to the branch owner/PR creator. You probably already know that you can set certain people (read: lead devs) as "required" on PRs and can even filter these auto-add people (we use groups of people) based on a directory or area in the repo being changed.

This will allow you and your other trusted devs to review code changes made, and will prevent the PR creator from getting any code into your `develop` or `master` branches without an authority figure approving the change. The actual completion of the PR is really just a token action. The real helpful information is to know who approved the request.

Giving branch and PR owners the responsibility for their feature branches and PRs will mitigate your issue for changing branch permissions so that you (not branch owner) can delete the other persons branch. It will also mitigate the mistaken delete issue, as the owner should know when the feature is complete.

Also IMHO, if the feature isn't done, done, it shouldn't get a PR.

Note too that deleting the source branch in AzDO doesn't effect the repository locally, until one does a `git remote prune origin` or has the IDE of choice do this periodically for them, so if a feature branch is deleted by mistake, there should be at least one copy of it somewhere on a dev workstation. We don't use the "periodically prune my remotes" option, and this is partly why.

Answer (score 1):

I have not worked with VSTS myself, but in other git hosters (gitlab and github) there's a thing called "Protected Branches".

For these protected branches ('master' and 'development' in my workflow) I overwrite the permissions to not let developers delete these branches (they can delete other branches as much as they like)

**Edit**

My memory was faulty. Protected branches can not be deleted (using git; they can still be deleted using the gitlab webpage). Permissions to allow accepting merge requests and to push to the branch can be set (see screenshot).[image: Gitlab protected branches screenshot]

Comment: That's similar to VSTS [branch permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28134314/protecting-a-git-branch-in-visual-studio-team-services), you're only protecting master and development.  I wish there was a way to have sort of a context-based way of setting permissions so that you could have a permission that would only apply in the context of completing a pull request.

Answer (score 1):

The rewrite and destroy history (force push) permission is required for corresponding branch to delete source branch.

By default, the branch owner has the permission to delete branch (new branch).  For others branch, you could specify that permission for specific users for specify branches, not need to specify that permission for whole group, after that you don’t need to specify the permission every time. (Select a branch, click Add=>Add User)

[image]

To conclude, there are two ways to do it, 1: create branches by pull request reviewer. 2: Grant rewrite and destroy history (force push) permission for pull request reviewer.