# Permission to stop check in code directly to master branch in VSTS

Tags: git, visual-studio, devops, azure-pipelines, azure-repos

Currently the deployment is setup in a manner that any developer can commit the code to master branch.

I want to change this way and setup the deployment in such a way that developer can make the changes in developer branch and to commit the same code to master branch they to send the merge/pull request to authorize person to commit the code to master branch.

can anyone tell me how is this possible.

Comment: Is your VCS TFS-VS or git? (In the latter case look at branch policies: you can require  use of PRs with approvals to apply.)

Comment: its git in my case

Comment: Related posts - [Protecting a git branch in Visual Studio Team Services](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28134314/465053) & [TFS-Git Branch Policies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44039439/465053)

Answer (score 2):

Azure DevOps-Repositories with git includes support for *Branch Policies* to include enforcing reviews, build quality, etc.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=vsts

You can also set permissions on branches (the next page in the documentation…).